# Apache HTTPS -> HTTP -> HTTPS 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am experiencing an issue that if any `RewriteRule` meets in `.htaccess`, it then does a `301` redirect from **https** to **http** then back to **https**

For instance, if I've a `301` redirect rule as follows

```
RewriteRule ^/products/?$ /en/products/ [R=301,L]
```

Then what it does is

```
+------------------------------------+
| https://example.com/products/      |
+----------------+-------------------+
                 |
                 v
+----------------+-------------------+
| http://example.com/en/products/    |
+----------------+-------------------+
                 |
                 v
+----------------+-------------------+
| https://example.com/en/products/   |
+------------------------------------+
```

Any idea, what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You have another rewrite to HTTPS somewhere, right?

Remove the L flag. [R=301,L] -> [R=301]. The L means last and it doens't look at the rules listed beneath that. That should do it if the HTTPS rewrite is after this one.

Another option is you can just direct it straight there:

```
RewriteRule ^/products/?$ https://{HTTP_HOST}/en/products/ [R=301,L]
```